# Are there examples of using Spring Boot with an exisitng MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mysql-workbench

I don't know how to actually map the service and controller part to the tables and can't find any good examples online.

Comment: Did you ask Google?

Comment: I did ask google and look at the documentation

Answer (score 1):

See the below examples: Spring io providers examples also.

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/
- https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate
- http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-example.

Answer (score 0):

just annotate your Entity classes, set up repositories, and let hibernate take care of all the messy sql scripting.